# Python3 Imprimir los resultados de 2 consultas en 1 sola tabla

Tags: python, informix

Tengo un problema, para crear una tabla con los resultados de 1 misma consulta a 2 bases de datos en diferentes servidores (Informix)

La consulta es:

```
SELECT fechaentrada, COUNT(*) AS conteopordia 
FROM productos 
WHERE estatus = 'abierto'
GROUP BY fechaentrada 
ORDER BY fechaentrada DESC
```

El primer resultado de la consulta a una base de datos 1 es:

`fechaentrada | conteopordia
   01/23/2020 | 50`

El segundo resultado de la consulta a una base de datos 2 es:

`fechaentrada | conteopordia
   01/23/2020 | 22
   01/22/2020 | 15`

Con Python estoy tratando de unir ambos resultados que me da en lists de esta forma:

```py
listado_completo = zip(consulta_server1,consulta_server2)
print(listado_completo)
((datetime.date(2020, 1, 23), Decimal('50'), (datetime.date(2020, 1, 23), Decimal('22')))
```

Me da los resultados de esta forma:

```
fechaentrada|conteopordia|fechaentrada|conteopordia
01/23/2020  |     50     |01/23/2020  |    22
```

Y el resultado que estoy buscando es algo asi:

```
fechaentrada|conteopordia|conteopordia
01/23/2020  |     50     |     22
01/22/2020  |      0     |     15
```

Tal vez exista alguna funcion para unir ambos resultados de consulta de esta forma, soy nuevo en python, si tienen alguna idea o informacion que pueda consultar, videos etc.

Comment: estas usando pandas?

Comment: Hola @LucasDamian no, solo me conecto a la base usando pyodbc 
```consulta_server1 = cursor.fetchall()
consulta_server2 = cursor.fetchall()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución puede ser utilizando `pandas`. 
Sólo deberías hacer esto:

```
import pandas as pd
cnxn1 = pyodbc.connect('Tu cadena de conexión')
cnxn2 = pyodbc.connect('Tu cadena de conexión')


consulta = '''SELECT fechaentrada, COUNT(*) AS conteopordia 
FROM productos 
WHERE estatus = 'abierto'
GROUP BY fechaentrada 
ORDER BY fechaentrada DESC'''

consulta1 = pd.read_sql(consulta,cnxn1)


#Aqui si usas otra base de datos, deberías crear una conexión nueva o cerrar la existente y abrir una nueva con el mismo nombre.

consulta2 = pd.read_sql(consulta,cnxn2) #

consulta_merge = pd.merge(consulta1, consulta2, on="fechaentrada",how="outer")
```

Y tu output debería ser el esperado. Siempre y cuando las consultan devuelvan el mismo nombre de columnas, se agregarán al final de `consulta1`

Comment: Me sirvio bastante tu ejemplo, solo hice unas modificaciones y quedo tal como esperaba, con el append lo que hice fue algo similar a un UNION, gracias a tu consejo logre encontrar pd.merge.  
Si modificamos tu ultima linea y lo sustituimos por:
tablacompleta = pd.merge(consulta1,consulta2, on="fechadeentrada",how="outer" 
Asi me trajo el listado completo y en los campos que me ignoraba me los rellena con NaN, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!